# extends not work : doesn't have zero argument constructor

Tags: dart

```dart
class Persons {
  final String name;
  final String age;
  Persons(
    this.name,
    this.age,
  );
  void printName() {
    print(name);
  }
}

class Players extends Persons {}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8esv.png)

Comment: Since `Players` extends `Persons`, the `Players` constructor must invoke the base class constructor.  Since you did not provide any constructor for `Players`, Dart will generate one for you that's equivalent to `Players() : super();`.  However, the base class constructor has required arguments.  What do you expect `Players().name` and `Players().age` to be?  You will need to provide an explicit `Players` constructor that explicitly invokes the base `Persons` constructor with the necessary arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the class Players

```dart
class Players extends Persons {
  Players(name, age): super(name, age);
}
```